# Save state in memory [Haskell Server]

Tags: haskell, scotty

I am attempting to create a server that returns two different values from a route depending if a user has visited it before. I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Web.Scotty

main = do
    putStrLn "Starting Server..."
    scotty 3000 $ do
        get "/" $ do
            -- if first time 
            text "hello!"
            -- if second time
            text "hello, again!"
```

I have two questions:
1. How can I check if a user has requested the route before?
2. Where and how can I persist application state?

Comment: You can add a cookie, and check the cookie to determine if this is the first visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `STM` to keep a mutable variable in memory:

```hs
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar

main = do
    putStrLn "Starting Server..."
    state <- newTVarIO :: IO VisitorsData
    scotty 3000 $ do
        get "/" $ do
            visitorsData <- readTVarIO state
            -- if the visitor's ID/cookie is in visitorsData
            text "hello!"
            -- if new visitor, add them to visitorsData
            atomically $ modifyTVar state $ insertVisitor visitorId visitorsData
            -- if second time
            text "hello, again!"
```

(If you expect to scale this to a complex server, you'll want to pass the TVar around in the form of a [ReaderT pattern](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern))